# attach icon issue from Fawesome

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

hope you can clarify this issue,

I am trying to use the Github Icon from fontawesome in react following the documentation:
[link to documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react),
but I am having an issue and getting this error:

```
./src/components/FindMe/FindMe.jsx
Attempted import error: 'faGithub' is not exported from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'.
```

My code is

```
//the imports from FA
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faGithub } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

//the icon as per documentation
 <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGithub} />
```

I tried changing the capital letters but nothing, also using fabGithub but does not work, different ways to do it folowing the documentation but also nothing, I tried with other icons and it works.

Hope someone can clarify

**edit
solved issue using this :**
[https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/#/[enter](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/#/%5Benter) link description here][2](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/#/)

Answer (score 2):

FontAwesome have divided icons into separate npm packaged.

Github Icon is in different package: `@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons`
so first you would need to install that

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

or

```
yarn add @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

and then use it in your code:

```js
import { faGithub } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

Comment: still does not work, is there any other npm package to install?

Comment: yes you need to install `@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons` first